# Inconsistent autolayout behavior between interface builder and programmatically created views

Tags: swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am trying to programmatically add a subview to a view inside a vertical stack view. It should try to maximize its size to fill its parent view but still keep its aspect ratio. I try to achieve it by adding an aspect ratio constraint with **default priority**. And add top, bottom, leading, trailing and centerX, centerY constraints with **low priority**. My prototype in interface builder works perfectly, but when I translate it into codes, the spacing at the borders are missing. Is there something missing in the programmatic version? Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var greenView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let testView = UIView()
        testView.backgroundColor = .red
        greenView.addSubview(testView)

        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let aspectRatioConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView,
                            attribute: .width,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: testView,
                            attribute: .height,
                            multiplier: 6.0 / 10.0,
                            constant: 0)

        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView,
                                             attribute: .leading,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: greenView,
                                             attribute: .leading,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 5)

        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView,
                                             attribute: .trailing,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: greenView,
                                             attribute: .trailing,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 5)

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView,
                                             attribute: .top,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: greenView,
                                             attribute: .top,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant:5)

        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView,
                                             attribute: .bottom,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: greenView,
                                             attribute: .bottom,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 5)

        let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView,
                                             attribute: .centerX,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: greenView,
                                             attribute: .centerX,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 0)

        let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView,
                                             attribute: .centerY,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: greenView,
                                             attribute: .centerY,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 0)

        leadingConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        trailingConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        topConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        bottomConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        centerXConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        centerYConstraint.priority = .defaultLow

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([aspectRatioConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint, centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint])

    }
}
```

The broken version created programmatically: The top and bottom spacing are missing.

[image]

The expected look built with Interface Builder:

[image: built with interface builder]

Here is the settings in IB:

[image: here is the setting in IB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to use `greaterThanOrEqual` for top and leading, and `lessThanOrEqual` for right and bottom.

Try it like this:

```
class ThiniumViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var greenView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let testView = UIView()
        testView.backgroundColor = .red

        greenView.addSubview(testView)

        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let tvHeightConstraint = testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 10.0 / 6.0)
        tvHeightConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh

        let tvWidthConstraint = testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0)
        tvWidthConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // center testView in greenView
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.centerXAnchor),
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.centerYAnchor),

            // constrain top and leading of redView to *at least* 5-points
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: greenView.topAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: greenView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5.0),

            // constrain height of testView to width of testView at 10:6 ratio at Priority 750
            tvHeightConstraint,

            // constrain width of testView to width of greenView at Priority 750
            tvWidthConstraint,

            // constrain bottom and trailing of redView to *at least* 5-points
            testView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: greenView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5.0),
            testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: greenView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5.0),

        ])

    }
}
```

As a side note, you may find it easier to write - and more readable - to construct your constraints as shown in my sample code.

Result:

[image]